# onCreateActionMode not being called on GridView long-press?

Tags: java, android, gridview

So I have a GridView that I want to be able to long-press elements to enable a contextual action bar right? I looked up lots of tutorials, including https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-2-choice-modes/ and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List15.java, as well as others which all state that when using CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL the MultiChoiceModeListener should automatically be used on a long-press

I see many tutorials using this (and that's it) and it works, but when I long press on elements in my GridView the CAB doesn't start (nor is onCreateActionView called at all) and I absolutely can't figure out why.

Here's my code for the GridView

```
receiptGridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            receiptGridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
                //                int count = 0;
                ArrayList<Receipt> tmp = new ArrayList();
                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG","Created action mode!");
                    MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_delete, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {

                    receiptGridView.setSelection(i);
                    Receipt r = (Receipt) listAdapter.getItem(i);
                    if(b) {
                        tmp.add(r);
                    }
                    else {
                        tmp.remove(r);
                    }
                    actionMode.setTitle("Delete Items");
                    actionMode.setSubtitle(receiptGridView.getCheckedItemCount() + " items selected.");
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_delete:
                            removeReceipts(tmp);
                            actionMode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode actionMode) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to *actually* trigger the action menu, you have to call setItemChecked on the gridview, so I just did this to my container view on longpress

```
holder.container.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if (ma.mActionMode == null) {


                    // the line that triggers it  
                    ma.receiptGridView.setItemChecked(position, true);


                    v.setBackgroundResource(b ? R.color.color_ce5a5a : R.drawable.receipt_item_bg);
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a"));
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```